# Alternative to window.frameelement.document.forms[0]?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, web-user-controls

I am looking at some code that is failing in current versions of Chrome and IE 11. 
It errors because of the line:

```
var form = window.frameElement.document.forms[0];
```

With error:

```
"JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'forms' of undefined or null reference"
```

Window and frameElement exist but the document is null.

The context of the above is a popup window take a zip code, displays some results and a "select" button.  On click of the button calls a method which calls the above line to then assign the selected location into some values.

```
returnValues(id, name){
  var form = window.frameElement.document.forms[0];
  form.ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$uxResControl$uxRenLoc$RenLocCodeField.value = id;
  form.ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$uxResControl$uxRenLoc$RenLocNameField.value = name;
  ...
}
```

With these nested user controls I am a bit confused as to how to "drill" down and assign the selected value to the hidden value RenLocCodeField or RenLocNanmeField.

Answer (score 0):

Using usual ASP.NET Javascript query is always a pain!

instead of the following line:

```
form.ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$uxResControl$uxRenLoc$RenLocCodeField.value = id;
form.ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$uxResControl$uxRenLoc$RenLocNameField.value = name;
```

you can use the following lines in javascript method, assuming `RenLocCodeField` and `RenLocNameField` are the `ID`s generated for the respective fields.

```
document.getElementById("RenLocCodeField").value = id;
document.getElementById("RenLocNameField").value = name;
```

Comment: I get 
    JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: It is quite possible that the id I used above `RenLocCodeField` was not the correct one. Please replace that with the correctly generated `Id`. You can find that from source of the generated HTML.

Comment: If I view source the name 
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$uxResControl$uxRenLoc$RenLocNameField" id="MainContentPlaceHolder_uxResControl_uxRenLoc_RenLocNameField" /> however the value is Null.

Comment: Might I add, I have to avoid ClientIDMode="Static" because this is code that is within an older 2.0 .net application.